# Issue creating a django user with python-social-auth with a custom User model and UserManager

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-social-auth

Seems like this isn't a unique problem, but I'm missing something in the solution.  I'm using `python-social-auth` and logging in with Google.  All seems to be going well, until it gets to the `create_user` part of the pipeline.  I do have a custom User model and UserManager.  On my User model I do have a `role` property that is hooked up to some `choices`.  When social auth kicks in and logs someone in, it does call `create_user` in my User manager, however it's only passing email, and no additional fields.  I was attempting to hook into the pipeline and add the required `role` property by adding it to the `details` social auth dict, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.  How should I go about hooking into the create user property to add fields that won't exist as far as social auth is concerned?

User Model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True)
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=RoleChoices.choices)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}".strip()
```

And my UserManager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_("The Email must be set"))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)

        if password is not None:
            user.set_password(password)

        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("role", 1)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_staff=True."))
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_superuser=True."))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

The Social auth config:

```
# Social Auth Config
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'admin'
SOCIAL_AUTH_POSTGRES_JSONFIELD = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID')
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET')
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'search.User'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'profile',
    'email'
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'search.socialauth.add_role',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

And finally the `add_role` function:

```
from .choices import RoleChoices


def add_role(**kwargs):
    kwargs['details']['role'] = RoleChoices.ARTIST
    return kwargs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is that the `create_user` function explicitly filters the contents of `details` to include only keys [specified in a `USER_FIELDS` setting](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/7ce07e90df78fdc1eaa5d088021d6a7632e23a9a/social_core/pipeline/user.py#L69). This defaults to

```
USER_FIELDS = ['username', 'email']
```

so anything else with just be ignored. It doesn't appear to be documented, but you should be able to override this by creating a setting as follows:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = ['username', 'email', 'role']
```

Which will then ensure your `role` is passed through to the user instance.

The rest of your pipeline and configuration looks fine.

Comment: You are 100% correct.  I ended up using `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USER_FIELDS` and it works as expected.  Thank you!